# how to call jquery selector from outside kendo window?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-window

I have kendo window with this following code, then how can I select jquery ID: btnValidateConfirmPin from outside kendo window? I also tried with $(document).on("click" it work but i don't know how to call $(this) in this event, any methods that could call selector directly from kendo window?

// Kendo Window
...

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()//Art add [2017-07-13]
<div class="formarea">
    <span class="h3-left"></span><h3 class="fixed-h3">@SharedResource.ConfrimPinHeader</h3><span class="h3-right"></span>
    <br />
    <div> ... </div>
    <div>
        <!-- this button -->
        <button id="btnValidateConfirmPin" class="button green" type="submit">@SharedResource.ContinueBotton</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

//outside kendo

```
$("#btnValidateConfirmPins").click(function (e) { //not work });

$(document).on("click","##btnValidateConfirmPins",function() { //work but how to call $(this)});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you would like to use the kendoWindow inside the `#btnValidateConfirmPins` method call.

You can use the kendoWindow ID to get that and call the `data("kendoWindow")` function. Example: `$("#YourKendoWindowID").data("kendoWindow")`

P.S.: The document click method has double `#` mark.

Comment: ah no, i have kendoWindow with holding btnValidateConfirmPins , but i want to call this from parent (not in kendo window), also how to call ("myKendoID").data("kendoWindow") -> btnValidateConfirmPins  onclick event ?

Comment: Make sense! :) what are you expecting by calling `$(this)` inside the `#btnValidateConfirmPins` `click` event? Returning the button or something else?

Comment: I want to press button inside kendo window then whenever click, the click event outside must be triggered. but now no matter i click on it, the click event won't launch.

Comment: You can try define the onclick method outside of kendo window. I guess the kendo window is rendered later by clicking on a button using ajax. 

So in detail: 
First: create a javascript method for the razor page like 

`function kendoButtonClick() {  console.log("Button clicked"); }`

Second: call this method by adding the `onclick` attribute for the button (inside kendo window):

`<button id="btnValidateConfirmPin" class="button green" type="button" onclick="kendoButtonClick();">@SharedResource.ContinueBotton</button>`

I have also changed the button type to `button`.